# Gradle Java Library Test Jar Using Maven Plugin

Tags: java, gradle

In the past, I've had great success in providing test helpers in a core or common project, and having those classes available to other sub-projects using the following:

Common Project A

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = "tests"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

artifacts { testRuntime testJar }
```

Dependent Project B

```
testCompile(project(path: ":project-a", configuration: "testRuntime"))
```

However, I have the same requirement between two projects that do NOT share a Gradle multi-project hierarchy.  To clarify, these are completely separate projects.  They are in different repositories, using different build scripts.  They are not sub-modules within a parent project.

To futher complex matters, I'm using the Java Library plugin and the Maven plugin to install libraries locally.  In other words, I'd love for the second project to include a dependency as such:

```
testImplementation 'com.mycompany:common-test:1.0.0'
```

What should the first "common" project look like to a) generate that test jar and b) allow it to be installed to Maven?

Many thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it's best to put any test utilities in their own separate project rather than building a "test" jar from `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`.

It seems that netflix feel the same as me. Previously they mentioned their [test-jar](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.test-jar) plugin as deprecated in their documentation, now it doesn't even get a mention in the [readme](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin/blob/master/README.md)